# Escape initial percentage on Product Search Criteria REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, search-criteria

I'm running the following request to search products by SKU using the Magento 2 REST API:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%24-MB01%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=like"
```

Summary: look for products with sku that contain the string **"24-MB01"**

Disregarding auth and content params, the issue is that the value **%24-MB01%** is misinterpreted as **$-MB01%** by the API as you can see:

```
{
   "total_count" : 0,
   "search_criteria" : {
      "filter_groups" : [
         {
            "filters" : [
               {
                  "condition_type" : "like",
                  "value" : "$-MB01%",
                  "field" : "sku"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "items" : []
}
```

How can I escape it?

Answer (score 0):

<s>You don't need to wrap the **sku** with **`%`**, you can directly put the **sku** and the condition **like** will do the search query for products with sku **`24-MB01`**</s>

You can try **`%2524-MB01%25`**

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%2524-MB01%25&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=like"
```

Comment: Without the `%` it's generating the wrong condition `WHERE ((e.sku LIKE '24-MB01'))` the result I'm expecting is `WHERE ((e.sku LIKE '%24-MB01%'))`

Comment: you can try updated answer

Comment: Now it's back to looking for `WHERE ((e.sku LIKE '$-MB01%'))` http://www.screencast.com/t/HUr1XOTdrrd3

Comment: hmm that is strange. I tested it in my machine using postman and it works. can you check in your postman first then check the curl code from there.

Comment: can you include your whole curl request code

Comment: That's the exactly command: `curl -X GET "http://localhost/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%24-MB01%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=like" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 01tcewo3flyforzum0ysi7kvoxz4y58q" -g`

Comment: everything seems right. that weird. can you try flushing the cache

Comment: and try again ...